# What is the proper way to determine usable screen dimensions in android

Tags: android, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb, dimensions

I know this question has been asked a few other times but I have yet to find a satisfactory answer. All previous answers work if you want the total screen resolution but fail to when you want to correct for the notification bar and/or the system bar in honeycomb.

Is there a way to determine the dimensions of the usable screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done previously is almost definitely not the *best* way: make a control that is set to fill the screen and then check its size. This is useful if you have a view you paint to in a game or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work.  In my layout file I added a button that is told "fill_parent" for both X and Y. In the activities onCreate method I get the button with findViewbyId and then then grab the height and width with button.getHeight() and button.getWidth(). When I run the test the button shows up on my phone and fills the screen however the values returned by getHeight() and getWidth() are both 0.

Comment: Right I had this issue as well. I think the issue was that it wasn't measured until after it drew once, so try getting the size afterwards at some point. I'll try to find my old code which had it working properly.

Comment: You're right it has to be drawn first. I moved the code from onCreate to onStop and I got the proper values. I'm holding out for a better way as these feels a bit too hackish for me.

Comment: I think if its done in onStart() it should work, try that. Or maybe onResume()

Comment: ok... this works as long as you don't need the information in the first activity that loads.